# Emacs GNUS change navigation keys to C-hjkl

Tags: keymap, gnus

I would like to use `C-hjkl` to navigate in gnus, so I wrote module for that keymap like this:

```
(require 'gnus)

;; GNUS crashed without this on `Key sequence C-h k starts with non-prefix key C-h`
(define-key gnus-article-mode-map (kbd "C-h") nil)
(define-key gnus-article-mode-map (kbd "C-h b") nil)
(define-key gnus-article-mode-map (kbd "C-h c") nil)
(define-key gnus-article-mode-map (kbd "C-h k") nil)
(define-key gnus-article-mode-map (kbd "C-h") 'backward-char)

(define-key gnus-article-mode-map (kbd "C-j") 'next-line)
(define-key gnus-article-mode-map (kbd "C-l") 'forward-char)
(define-key gnus-article-mode-map (kbd "h") 'backward-char)
(define-key gnus-article-mode-map (kbd "l") 'forward-char)

(define-key gnus-group-mode-map (kbd "C-k") 'previous-line)
(define-key gnus-group-mode-map (kbd "C-w") 'forward-word)
(define-key gnus-group-mode-map (kbd "j") 'next-line)
(define-key gnus-group-mode-map (kbd "k") 'previous-line)
(define-key gnus-group-mode-map (kbd "s-w") 'gnus-group-exit)

(define-key gnus-mode-map (kbd "C-j") 'next-line)
(define-key gnus-mode-map (kbd "C-k") 'previous-line)

(define-key gnus-summary-mode-map (kbd "C-k") 'previous-line)
(define-key gnus-summary-mode-map (kbd "C-l") 'forward-char)
(define-key gnus-summary-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'gnus-summary-scroll-up-same-window)
(define-key gnus-summary-mode-map (kbd "j") 'next-line)
(define-key gnus-summary-mode-map (kbd "k") 'previous-line)
(define-key gnus-summary-mode-map (kbd "s-w") 'gnus-summary-exit)

(provide 'gnus-keymap)
```

But after I start `M-x gnus` I get error `gnus-define-keys-1: Key sequence C-h k starts with non-prefix key C-h` I tried to require that module either in .emacs or in .gnus but it always crashes after starting gnus.

Comment: Are you using plain standard GNU Emacs, or are you using eg Doom Emacs? If the former, then `C-h` is the prefix for the Help keymap, and you probably should think long and hard before changing it.

Comment: I use plain GNU Emacs and still it is common that `C-h` is help, but, normally I just can make change in major mode map and it works, it seems like gnus is not simply defining mode keymap, but calling some function on first startup that will define keymap, also it seems .gnus is run before this keymap definition function is executed, maybe if there is some hook after gnus started where I can override that function, did not put mi self to actualy explore gnus source code, elpa is downloading compiled and gziped packages